# Set password runtime with Hibernate / JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a web app with a db connection properties defined in persistence.xml.

I am using contained manager persistence with the entity manager injected using @PersistenceContext.

Today the password to the DB is in the persistence.xml file, but I would rather set it runtime (ask the user for it).

I am able to create a new EntityManager with the password runtime, but how can I "override" the injected one?

Any other good ideas/approaches?

Comment: Rather than explicitly asking the user, it's preferable to use a property or environment variable.

Comment: The client will be run "locally" and not installed in proper production environment, and we don't want the production password in local files. They know what password to use towards the database, and will provide it  runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a bit worried with configuring the profiles for different environments.

Though it wont suffice your "runtime" setting of the password and replace the object, but it would be maintained as the spring bean profiles.

Something like this;

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class StandaloneDataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/schema.sql")
            .addScript("classpath:com/bank/config/sql/test-data.sql")
            .build();
    }

}
```

Lets say you want to load the profile for production ?

You have to define another profile with `@Profile("production")` and load the properties file from the classpath location.

With spring boot, you can activate your profile as

`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production mvn spring-boot:run`

This can make you to change the password and bounce the server whenever it is required. Anyways as you change the password, the connection needs a reboot. So ideally this should make the job easy.

Comment: I think this is a bit on the side. The issue is not about having multiple environments, but rather how to combine container managed persistence with supplying password when application already is running.